# How to use a block element as a HTML form label?

Tags: html, forms

The HTML tag `<label>` may not contain block elements by definition. The following code is wrong in HTML 4, although ist works in most browsers:

```
<input type="radio" value="A" name="ABC" id="ABC_A">
<label for="ABC_A">
  <p>Option A</p>
  <p>Having a good time with HTML.</p>
</label>
```

I could make a block element from the `<label>` via CSS, but this still remains invalid HTML code. And in some instances, it makes sense to format one label into multiple paragraphs.

**My question is: Is there a valid way in HTML to use block elements as a label for an input?**

Possible workarounds, that I have considered inappropriate are:

- Creating one label within each paragraph (why should one input have a dozend labels - and which one should a screen reader read, then?)
- Using JavaScript to have the input "clicked" when the block element is clicked. I am searching for a solution that will work without scripting (and that is supported by vommon screen readers)

And ideas? Thank you!

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that requires the `<label>` to be, or to contain, a block-type element?

Comment: Are you completely against CSS based solutions? I would use a span and make it `display: block`.

Comment: @David Thomas: The description of an option simply is a bit more complex. For sake of readability, multiple paragraphs are required. And regarding usability, the

Comment: @Rutwick Gangurde: Are you thinking about a <span> in the <label> and the block elements in the <span>? As <span> is an inline element, it does not allow block elements as content in HTML 4, does it? My goal is having a green result in the W3C Validator ;) Technically, already paragraphs within a <label> work fine in most browsers.

Comment: Why do you need the `p` at all? I'm saying you can remove the `p` completely.

Comment: The `label` element is supposed to provide a *label* for a control, briefly showing what the control is about. If you need to write a *description* of what the control means, simply put it outside the `label` element (before or after the control and its label, or maybe on its right or left).

Comment: I could try to find a part within the long description that described the control in a nutshell (actually, I cannot, because others add the texts, not me). But it would be a usability issue, if the users cannot click anywhere in the description to enable the (e.g.) radio button. But as it seems, the <label> is not genuinely intended to be clicked...

Comment: On http://usability.com.au/2013/04/accessible-forms-1-labels-and-identification/ I found a striking argument, why more information may be very useful for a form field: "With the virtual buffer off (‘forms’  or ‘browse off’ mode), the user is able to enter content into form fields, but can only move easily between objects on the page that can accept focus (e.g. form inputs and links). As a result, the user needs to switch out of ‘forms’ mode if they wish to read any headings or text that might be between form fields."